# CSRF token AJAX based post in a Django Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, csrf

So I found out the error and it was in my HTML. I just added `{% csrf_token %}` and it worked :) thanks for the assist guys!

> (I used the JS snippet given to me in the first answer but I am still
>   getting a 403 Forbidden error!) what could I be doing wrong?

I recently learnt JS and tried the following JS code for AJAX POST but I am getting a 403 error. Did some further research and found that I needed to pass a CSRF token. I have gone through a lot of tutorials online but the only solutions I was able to find were of JQuery and I have no idea how that syntax works. I need to know how to pass a CSRF token via Javascript AJAX based post for a django project. My code is;

```
var upvoteBtn = document.querySelector('#upvote');
var downvoteBtn = document.querySelector('#downvote');

upvoteBtn.addEventListener('click', jL);
downvoteBtn.addEventListener('click', cL);

function jL(event) {
    document.getElementById("upvote").style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("downvote").style.display='none';
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    var url = 'entered my url here';
    var data = 'title=Post%20Title&body=Body';
    var method = 'POST';

    http.open(method, url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    http.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status === 200){
        document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "this post has been voted";
        console.log("upvote given");
    }
    else if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status !== 200){
        console.log("error!", http.responseText);
    }
};

http.send(data);
}

function cL(event){
    document.getElementById("upvote").style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("downvote").style.display='none';
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    var url = 'entered my url here';
    var data = 'title=Post%20Title&body=Body';
    var method = 'POST';

    http.open(method, url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    http.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status === 200){
        document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "got downvoted";
        console.log("downvoted!");
    }
    else if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status !== 200){
        console.log("error!", http.responseText);
    }
}; 
http.send(data);
}

//function for CSRF token
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}    
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

[image: this is the error I receive when I clicked on the button mentioned in my code to send some data]

Comment: Look at your browser's Network monitor and compare the value Django sends to you in the `Cookie` header with what your JavaScript code sends back to Django in the `X-CSRFToken` header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
```

when you prepare your `xhr` request. (in your example `xhr` is named `http`)

you can get the `csrftoken` from the cookie, but in order to do that you need to implement a `getCookie` function.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

### Update

In your code this should look something like this:

```
upvoteBtn.addEventListener('click', jL);
downvoteBtn.addEventListener('click', cL);

//first define your getCookie function
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function jL(event) {
    //...
    //Then when you prepare you data fetch the token
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    http.open(method, url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    //Now set it
    http.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    //... the rest of your code
}

function cL(event){
    //do the same here
}
```

Comment: so i am still getting a Forbidden 403 error after adding the code as you instructed. Though I added the http request right after http.open. what could i be doing wrong? I tried adding the code here but it wouldn't let me :(

Comment: Thats strange, I can open it w/o problems. Try with this one: http://pastebin.com/raw/Zks2hkJ7

Comment: :( Same error as before;
Not Found
The requested URL /raw/Zks2hkJ7 was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at pastebin.com Port 80

can you please add the code by either adding it here if its short or just editing my original post at the end and saying it is a possible solution?

Comment: @shahz yes, just updated my answer, hope it helps now.

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code into your JS:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = $.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}

if (!csrfSafeMethod(http.responseType) && sameOrigin(http.responseUrl)) {
    http.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
}
```

Basically you need to add the CSRF token to the headers. I cannot find the link where I found this piece of code, if anyone knows would be great.

Comment: hey I tried using your comment but at first I got an error that http is not defined and then later on i got Uncaught ReferenceError: csrftoken is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.jL (button.js:49) when i defined http as a variable which I was already doing in my code as mentioned above.

Comment: I just added the code you gave me right at the end of the code I have pasted for this question

Comment: I cannot replicate your code, so you'll have to give detailed error. Giving the line where the error happens is not going to help. Anyway, you had to add my code after your `Content-Type` header. Well, the functions can go out, but the `if` must go there.

Comment: I have updated the code in my original question and have also added the screenshot of the error message. Though the new updated code does not have the code you gave me but I also tried your way by keeping 3 functions out but the if statement right underneath the "Content-Type" and I still ended up with the same error as mentioned above.